# ImageMagick or CoreImage lib for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, imagemagick, photo, core-image

I'm looking for a tutorial / example to use ImageMagick lib for iphone

- You know you tell me where I can find this?
- CoreImage you think is better to use?

Comment: You should write about your goal so we can tell you what we think suits better to solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link for imagegick :

http://www.cloudgoessocial.net/2010/05/01/latest-imagemagick/